# Magento hiding all errors page

Tags: php, error-handling, magento

Magento Production version 1.2.1
store running on linux centos.

I want to hide all error messages generating from Magento, or if error occurred then I want user to send to custom error page. I tried some solutions like putting

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
in index.php but it is not working properly,

I even tried to set ini_set('display_errors', 0); but it is still not working. Magento still giving errors like "undefined index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the proper answer for this question and here are the steps I followed

Setting the reporter up to use this feature is simple.
   1. Find the config.xml file in the /report directory.
   2. Change  from print to email.
   3. Set  to the email address that you would like the report to go to.
   4. Done.

This setting will not show error messages and will send all errors to mail id mention on step 3.

:)  happy to solved the error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about "print to email"? Change what? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this version report/config.xml has been replaced by errors/local.xml